# Which function can I use to fit my plot? Looks like a sigmoid function with a dip at the top

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

I was wondering which function I could use to fit to the following plot:

[image]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is there only one dip or there might be more of them?

Comment: There is only 1 dip!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this maybe? A slope with steepness controlled by $\alpha$, and subtract a bell curve centered at $d$ with width controlled by $\gamma$ and vertical scaling controlled by $\beta$:
$$\frac{e^{-\alpha x}}{1-e^{\alpha 
   x}}+1-\beta  \left(e^{-\frac{(x-d)^2}{2 \gamma }}\right)$$

[image: the sigmoid curve with dip]

Other than that, if you want curve where you know precisely $a$,$b$,$c$,$d$,$e$,$f$ then I suggest breaking it into a piecewise  curve.

Edit:
The above is not so great near zero. This below is a bit simpler for curve fitting:
$$
1-e^{-\alpha(x-p)}-\beta e^{-\frac{(x-d)^2}{2 \gamma }}
$$

Comment: That looks exactly like what I was looking for! Thanks a lot!